# Why is the `the` determiner missing before the word camp?

Tags: articles, zero-article

In the following sentence:

> I don't think I can make it back to camp—you go on without me!

[Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+it+to)

I would expect it to be "*to the camp*".

Comment: "...English is my fourth language" - no need to brag ;)

Comment: I didn't know I was bragging... I just said that to add some context. You folks living in the West have some serious issues to handle ;)

Comment: Thank you BruceWayne, I was merely joking as well, but on a second thought it seems to me that there may be some grain of truth in what you said. I'll remove the incriminating evidence...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For historical reasons, some words for places don't always require an article. "Camp" is one of those words. All of these are correct, for instance:

> 1. My father is **at church**.
> 2. Joe got sent back **to jail**.
> 3. Sally's **in hospital** again.

There's a special rule that governs this usage though: *the article is only optional if the place is being used for its intended purpose*. This means that in sentence 1, my father is attending religious services at the church, not using the recreation facilities; in sentence 2 that Joe is a criminal, not a prison worker; and in sentence 3 that Sally is a patient of the hospital, not a visitor or a staff person.

In your example, it means the two people in the story are using the camp as a camp. And if it was, for example, an abandoned camp, and they were just meeting some people there, then they would have to say:

> I don't think I can make it back to **the** camp

Comment: Americans tend to say 'in the hospital', I have noticed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, "hospital" doesn't completely follow these rules in all varieties of English.

Comment: Actually, "hospital" is excellent proof of your claim because it illustrates that history is what counts here rather than some logical principle.

Comment: Any particular citation for this rule? (Not that I doubt it, just interested.)

Comment: @chepner I've seen it in several ESL textbooks, but there wasn't a name attached to it. [This site](https://www.linguahouse.com/learning-english/general-english/nouns-2-special-omissions-of-the-definite-article) just calls it a "*special omission of the definite article*" (number 2 on that page), but that's obviously not an academic term

Comment: Is this the same situation as when political activists refer to ‘conference’ without an article, meaning their party's annual conference or whatever? I've also noticed it with ‘carnival’ (to mean the Notting Hill Carnival, I think). (I'm not condoning such usages — I find them quite confusing…)

Comment: @gidds Can you cite a usage of "conference" or "carnival" used without an article? I can't say I've heard either. Straight off though, neither one is a building, so it's unlikely the grammar would work

Comment: For me at least (Canadian English), the at X construction implies some standard action as well. If someone is at church, they are attending the standard religious gathering, not just present there. If someone is in hospital, they are sick and a patient-it would be wrong to say that Sally is in hospital if she's just visiting. If someone is sent to jail, they've been imprisoned, they're not a guard or similar.

Comment: @gotube "[I have been to Conference before, do I need to apply again?](https://labour.org.uk/conference/faqs/)", "[First time at Conference?](https://www.libdems.org.uk/first-timers)", "[Take a look at how you can get involved at Conference](https://www.conservatives.com/conference/business)", "[ACTIVITIES AT CONFERENCE](https://contagious.org.uk/conferences/activities/)", and the BBC2 programme [Today at Conference](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00dnk3z/episodes/guide).

Comment: @gotube "[Frequently asked questions on street trading at Carnival](https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/leisure-and-culture/filming-and-special-events/street-trading-notting-hill-carnival)", "[…on the parade route at Carnival.](https://nhcarnival.org/mas-bands)", "[Notable events leading up to Carnival include…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival)", "[Carnival, the merrymaking and festivity that takes place in many Roman Catholic countries…](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Carnival-pre-Lent-festival)".

Comment: @gidds "Conference" and "Carnival" are proper nouns in those examples. The usage is the same as referring to other events like Comic-Con or Coachella.

Comment: @d_b It's not quite the same, though, is it? ‘Conservative Party Conference’ is a proper noun, but it still takes an article — why would the article be dropped when shortening it?

Comment: "School" would be a good example, similar to "camp", where it can go either way.  "I went back to school" is a more general sense of going back for additional education after finishing school presumably years before.  "I went back to *the* school" implies that you'd just physically left a specific school building/campus and then returned, not necessarily for an education.  (You might be a teacher, parent, administrator, etc.)

Comment: Sometimes a missing article isn't so definite (to coin a phrase). "Mary is in class" doesn't imply a particular class, but just some undetermined class.

Comment: With regard to the American usage of "in the hospital", it is also a special use of the word "the" in that it doesn't necessarily indicate that the particular hospital being referred to has come up in the discussion before. It is analogous to "on the telephone."

Comment: Thanks @gidds for the examples. Some, like using "Carnival" to mean "the Notting Hill Carnival", and referring to "the Conservative Party Annual Conference" as "Conference" are unnatural to me, a Canadian native speaker. My best guess is that over time, in the local culture of those events, it became acceptable to drop the article for those events. There is no standard rule of English that explains it.

Comment: @gidds The other about "Carnival" are correct because the original meaning of the word is the name of that festival, without an article. The word has come to have a more generic meaning, like a fun public event with games and entertainment, and that generic meaning of the word requires an article

Comment: @gotube Interesting, thanks. (If it's any consolation, it feels completely unnatural to me too, even though I'm a UK native! It always bugs me when I see it. As you say, maybe you need to be a member of the relevant cultures…)

Answer (score 4):

In such constructions, the determiner is optional. Sometimes it depends on the context and whether you are referring to a particular camp.

**Back to camp/base/headquarters** are all general descriptions rather than particular locations.

If you were referring to a particular camp or base, you would need the determiner.

Equally, you would need the determiner in phrases such as **back to the office/factory/stadium/sports ground** because you would be referring to particular locations.

Comment: In this example though, they are referring to a specific camp.

Comment: @gotube True, but it's one of those examples where the determiner is optional, possibly as an established expression, as in **Let's head back to camp/base**.. The meaning is the same with or without it.

Comment: Your answer says we need the determiner in the OP's example sentence, but we do not.

Comment: **"In such constructions, the determiner is optional.**.

Comment: @Lambie "*If you were referring to a particular camp or base, you would need the determiner.*" This is a particular camp, but we don't need the determiner, so this claim is false

Comment: "**Let's head back to camp/base.. The meaning is the same with or without it**." Same as: Let's head back to the camp.

Comment: I would have said there are two cases: (1) the location is contextually implicit, e.g. the only camp the speaker could be referring to is their own or (2) when what is being conveyed is the _state_ of being in the location, e.g. "Alice is in hospital/school/prison".

Comment: It's not a particular camp. The person is saying "I cannot make it back to any camp" (or any reasonable camp, any camp that would have me). If you are wounded or dying, you don't care which camp you go to.